# How to convert base64 image to blob in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working with ionic 3 framework.and i don't know how to convert base64 image to blob Thank you.

.ts file

```
openCamera() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: 'Edit Your Profile Picture',
      buttons: [
        {
          text:'Camera',
          icon: 'ios-camera',
          role: 'destructive',
          handler: () => {
            const options: CameraOptions = {
              quality: 100,
              destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
              saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
              mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
            }

            this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
              this.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

            }, (err) => {
              alert(err)
            });
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Gallery',
          icon: 'ios-images',
          handler: () => {
            const options: CameraOptions = {
              quality: 50,
              destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
              encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
              mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
              correctOrientation: true,
              sourceType:this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            }

            this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
              // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
              // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):

              this.image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
              //this.image = base64Image;
             // alert(base64Image);
            }, (err) => {
              // Handle error
              console.log(err);
            });
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {

          }
        }
      ]
    });

    actionSheet.present();
  }
```

.html file

```
 <img (click)="openCamera()" [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image)" class="before-img" >
```

Comment: Please clarify what problem you are running into, are you getting an error etc?

Comment: yes :- data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.toon.com/cache/IMG-20190117-WA0006.jpg?1547785733893:1 GET data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.toon.com/cache/IMG-20190117-WA0006.jpg?1547785733893 net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Answer (score 0):

Default setting is the file URI (blob) according to this:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/#CameraOptions

So you can alter your current options here to request FILE URI instead of DATA URL (as your current options set to use DATA URL which is base64):

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
              quality: 50,
              destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
              encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
              mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
              correctOrientation: true,
              sourceType:this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
}
```

You can also omit setting this explicitly and then in theory the default will be used...

Comment: getting error :data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.toon.com/cache/IMG-20190117-WA0006.jpg?1547785733893:1 GET data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.toon.com/cache/IMG-20190117-WA0006.jpg?1547785733893 net::ERR_INVALID_URL